# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'torch' has no attribute 'autograd' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: torch, flair

I'm trying to run code for sentiment analysis of a file using python flair. However it gives me AttributeError in torch on ubutnu 22.04.  **Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ayush/myproj/vaahan/scrape/sentimentF.py", line 9, in <module>
    from flair.models import TextClassifier
  File "/home/ayush/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flair/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/home/ayush/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 759, in <module>
    from .serialization import save, load
  File "/home/ayush/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 21, in <module>
    from transformers.models.bert.modeling_bert import BertModel,BertForMaskedLM
  File "/home/ayush/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py", line 26, in <module>
    import torch.utils.checkpoint
  File "/home/ayush/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/checkpoint.py", line 55, in <module>
    class CheckpointFunction(torch.autograd.Function):
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'torch' has no attribute 'autograd' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

this is my **code:**

```
from flair.models import TextClassifier
from flair.data import Sentence
sia = TextClassifier.load('en-sentiment')

def getSentiment3():
    with open("/home/ayush/myproj/vaahan/scrape/scrapeListFile.txt","r") as f:
        content = f.read()  
        flair_analysis = Sentence(content)
        sia.predict(flair_analysis)
        score = flair_analysis.labels[0]

        return score

print(getSentiment3())
```

Answer (score 0):

The error got removed with removing and adding torch

```
pip uninstall torch
pip install torch
```